# Redirect with Spring MVC 3.1.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller I'm using

```java
return new ModelAndView( "redirect:new_page" );
```

now I changed Spring version from 3.0.6 to 3.1.2 and I found that it's not working in new version.

My Controller is defined like

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class MyController {
```

I tried to use

- `"redirect:/new_page"`
- `"redirect:/test/new_page"`
- `"redirect:./new_page"`

and nothing helped, any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Does it send status code 404, 403, 500 or maybe return garbage?

Comment: There is no error in log/console. Flow simply returns/stays on the same page. I will add some info to question...

Comment: Can you show whole Controller code?

Comment: I found the problem, but still I do not know the reason why there is different behaviour (see the answer please)...

Comment: @Betlsita I am having a similar problem where there is no error in log/console. What was the fix to your problem?

Comment: @robbr It's not clear from question, my problem was, that return type of the controller method was `Object`, when I changed it to `ModelAndView` it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem you had is using Object as return type, which, [accoring to Spring MVC reference  manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types), isn't dispatched as view name or `ModelAndView`:

> - Any other return type is considered to be a single model attribute to
>     be exposed to the view, using the attribute name specified through
>     `@ModelAttribute` at the method level (or the default attribute name
>     based on the return type class name). The model is implicitly enriched
>     with command objects and the results of `@ModelAttribute` annotated
>     reference data accessor methods.

I guess you used some undocumented / internal part of Spring MVC, which implementation changed in new release.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Spring 3.0.6 controller like this one is ok:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/dialog")
public class DialogController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirected.view")
    public ModelAndView redirected() {
        System.out.println( "DialogController.redirected()" );
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView( "redirected" );
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/form.view")
    public Object form() {
        System.out.println( "DialogController.form()" );
        return createModel();
    }

    private ModelAndView createModel() {
        final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView( "redirect:redirected.view" );
        return mav;
    }

}
```

notice the `Object` return type for `form()`...

when I change Spring version to 3.1.2 it's returning 404 - it cannot find
`WEB-INF/jsp/dialog/form.jsp`, that's strange.

Yes, I'm using viewResolver

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Method in original code was yet more complicated

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object submit( @Valid @ModelAttribute("sequentialSearch") final SequentialSearchData searchObject,
        final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, final HttpSession session ) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

and probably that's the reason why error is not shown...

I had there `Object`, because I returned `String` or `ModelAndView`, now I'm returning always `ModelAndView`, so I can change the return type and it works.

Comment: why you are using the ModelAndView Object in spring 3 you can return only a string represents the view name only.

Comment: @ProgMania that's not really true, [you can return other objects](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) too, only returning `Object` does not mean it'll be dispatched as `View`.

Comment: @Xaerxess yes you can return other object as declared, i'm saying that returning string represents the view name is much easier.